# Do we need to install a webserver for a webservice to work, always?

Tags: web-services, web, webserver

I will be having a software which will give me information about the moving vehicles on the server side and I need to pass this information to the client computer on demand.

There will be a website which will act like a server and another website will act like a client. The client
website will ask for a data from the server website.

From here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2849683/462608

> As the protocol may not be HTTP, you may provide WebServices over mail or other protocols, and you do not need a web server for that.

I request an explanation on the above quote. In my case will I be needing a webserver?

Comment: For what? The client or the server?

Comment: @Oded I don't know where it is "needed". :(

Comment: If you are going to use a website to host the client and a website to host the server, then of course you need a web server.

Comment: @Oded One website on one computer will act like a client ,and other website on other computer will act like a server. You meant the same?

Comment: They can be different computers. But my point is - you can't have a website running without a web server.

Comment: @Oded Okay, thanks. Now, as an answer, I think a detailed explanation of in which cases the webserver is not needed, will be helpful.

Comment: To be honest, I think you are getting hung up on semantics, and that the OP of that answer was being less than accurate. By definition a web service runs on a web server as if it is not accessible through the web, it is not a web service. The OP probably thought about other ways to offer services over the Internet (like an email server that can process emails in a special way), but I wouldn't normally call these web services.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bunch of [webservice protocols](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_protocols), some of them may use and some may not use `http` as [transport layer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_services_protocol_stack). When `http` is used - you need a webserver on server-side of your service and a webbrowser as a client. If the transport is other than `http`, you need server of other type, and other client, for example, mail server and mail client in case of running service over `smtp`.